# how to integrate google hindi input tools in android application

Tags: android, localization, hindi

I am working on an android application and wanted users to type and input the data in local language using Google Input Tools.How Can I integrate that one? Or is there any other way to do that

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Won't the user already have a keyboard installed that supports the language he wants to use?  Because on Android you can install different keyboards, plenty of hindi ones exist.

Comment: I guess it's out of developer's hand to set the specific keyboard if it's not installed.

Comment: @GabeSechan it's a very tough job for one to search the characters and type and it consumes time.As in the Input tools the user has to just type the word in english and it will convert them to our local language with some suggesions.

Comment: @AndrewT. It is, but the user can easily change.  In fact, most of the big keyboards support 40-50 languages built in, changable by pressing a button.  And if they speak both languages, they'll have it set up already.

Comment: @anaghvj Are you trying to do this for people who don't speak the language?  If so, automatic translation is pretty terrible-  I've tried it when traveling and it rarely works.  When it does, its like talking to a 3 year old-  grammatically incorrect and difficult to understand, although maybe better than nothing.  If you're doing it for people who do speak the language, having them type in their native language on their preferred keyboard will be order of magnitudes faster and more accurate.

Comment: @GabeSechan & Andrew you both are right. And that's an only option that the user type In using the personalised locale keyboard.. But what I need that the user just type the word in English like "main" and it would get translated into Hindi like "मैं" just after typing the word in English . Or for better understanding go with this sentence flow "main ja raha Hun." -> "मैं जा रहा हूँ ।" (so this should work in android app like "main ->मैं ja ->जा   Raha ->रहा hun-> हूँ |" the user types faster with this type of solution.

Comment: As most of the users or say a maximum users In India texts each other in this pattern "hinglish" instead of using typical Hindi keyboard.

Comment: There are hinglish keyboards out there too.  I know that one of my coworkers at Swype was working on the hinglish dictionary as I left 2 years ago (just checked-  its in there).  So letting them choose a hinglish keyboard on their own is still a better option.